# JQuery extend transforms string in array

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a jquery plugin and extending default options, like this:

```
$.fn.myplugin = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
        myOption: true
    }

    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options); // <---- this line is important

    /* stuff */
}
```

if I call `$('selector').myplugin('999.999')` the 'important' line above transforms string '999.999' to an array, and `options` holds `{'9', '9', '9', '.', '9', '9', '9' }`.

What should I do to keep `options` as a string '999.999'?

Another approach, same problem:

```
var defaults = { some: 'thing' };
var options = 'foo';

// all code below returns an Object { 0: "f", 1: "o", 2: "o", some: "thing" }
$.extend(false, {}, defaults, options)
$.extend(true, {}, defaults, options)
$.extend(defaults, options)

// The expected is Object { 0: "foo", some: "thing" }
```

Some help?

Comment: What should be the result of calling `$.extend()` with two objects and a string? You should have a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) for the correct usage of `$.extend()`. Spoiler: "Merge the contents of two or more **objects** together into the first object" ;)

Comment: Did you even open the link I've posted? `$.extend()` combines two or more **objects** into one. To solve your problem (which makes no sense, imho) transform the string into an object with key `0` and the string as value and pass this instead of `options` into `$.extend()`

Answer (score 0):

Just use...

```
.join("")
```

At the end of the array to convert it into a string.

```html
<script>
  document.write(['9', '9', '9', '.', '9', '9', '9'].join(""));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But it's not what I want. The array is created in jquery.extend code and I don't want hack it.

Comment: @Moesio What exactly you wanna do and not wanna do?

Comment: Question was edited with another approach and same problem.